# How to use Google Contacts API from Ruby client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, google-contacts-api

Google's official Ruby client is here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client

but there is no `Contacts` in `generated/google/apis`

Is Contacts API special? How to use it then in v0.9 of the client?

I managed to read contacts in 0.8.6 by doing this

```
def execute(options = {})
  @client.execute({ headers: { 'GData-Version' => '3.0', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }}.merge(options))
end

def fetch_all(options = {})
  execute(uri: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full",
          parameters: { 'alt' => 'json',
                        'max-results' => '100000' }).data
end

def contacts
  fetch_all['feed']['entry'].map do |contact|
    {
      phone: Phone.normalize((contact['gd$phoneNumber'] || []).map { |r| r['$t'] }.first),
      email: (contact['gd$email'] || []).map { |r| r['address'] }.first,
      name: contact['gd$name'] && contact['gd$name']['gd$fullName'] && contact['gd$name']['gd$fullName']['$t']
    }
  end.select { |contact| contact[:phone] && contact[:name] }
end
```

This is now [deprecated](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md) and also I couldn't figure out how to create or edit contacts so I want to use the latest gem.

Comment: Appears that you need to use the [Mirror](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/generated/google/apis/mirror_v1/service.rb) service. Available APIs are listed [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/tree/master/generated/google/apis). Had you considered use easy libraries, like [CloudSponge](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/ruby)?